# Web scraper to collect data into Excel

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm stuck on my first ever web scarper, it opens the browser, but does nothing then, could you help me out please?

````
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
products=[]
prices=[]
ratings=[]
driver.get = ("<a href=https://www.flipkart.com/laptops-store?otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Laptops")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True, attrs={'class' : '_3YgSsQ'}):
    name=a.find('div', attrs={'class' : '_2rpwqI'})
    price = a.find('div', attrs={'class': '_30jeq3'})
    rating = a.find('div', attrs={'class': '_3LWZlK _1wB99o'})
    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)
    ratings.append(rating.text)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name': products, 'Price': prices, 'Rating': ratings})
    df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')```
````

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `driver.get` with a URL, rather than assigning the string representation of an element to it? Compare what you've posted to e.g. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage.

Answer (score -1):

### get(url: str)

[get(url)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) loads a web page in the current browser session, which accepts a *url: string*

As per the line of code:

```
driver.get = ("<a href=https://www.flipkart.com/laptops-store?otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Laptops")
```

you are passing the partial *HTML* markup of the desired [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) which would result in an error. Instead you need to pass the *`url: str`* as follows:

```
driver.get = ("https://www.flipkart.com/laptops-store?otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Laptops")
```